# Event related to node - how to display?

Tags: views, nodes, entities

Thinking how to achieve what I need, looking into possibilities. I have a content type that is used for all kind of locals: restaurants, clubs and so on. Now, what I want is to have a list of nearest 3 events that will take place in that specific place.

So far I was thinking about creating new type of nodes for events. Let's say: Event content. Seems logical, right? Now, using Entity Reference I should be able somehow to add relation between an event and club (not sure about this one yet). Next step would be displaying this added event on the node of that club. How could I achieve that? Creating a View and putting it into the node display somehow? Block?

Really could use some ideas for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a view and add relationship using node reference(entity reference) and after adding relationship you should add fields corresponding to node for which relationship has been added.
Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865746/drupal-views-relationship) on how to add relationship in views